# how to check status of multiple UISwitch controls in a table view with custom cell using tag property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a tableview with custom UITableViewCell. Cell have a `UISwitch` controls. I have added cell  into the table view controller with the same action for all switches. I have added tag value of `UISwitch` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

I want to determine what switch was changed, when user changed the switch status on/off. Here I am setting action on  `UISwitch` button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    cell.switchbtn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [cell.switchbtn setOn:YES];
    [cell.switchbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:   UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.switchbtn];
}
```

Here I am setting tag value of uiswitch

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cellid";
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cellid" owner:self options:nil];

    }

    cell.switchbtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"btn tag=%d",cell.switchbtn.tag);
    return cell;
}
```

Here I am calling switchToggled: method to get the uiswitch status.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  [self switchToggled:cell.switchbtn];
}
```

I am gettting tag value and each time status is On .even i status is off.

```
- (void) switchToggled:(UISwitch *)sender {
    UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

    NSLog(@"tag ==%@",mySwitch);
    if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"its on!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"its off!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not save state in the View. I wrote some sample code for switches in a tableView a while ago, you might consider a dedicated datasource like I did in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264207/ios-loop-through-cells-and-retrieve-data/9264395#9264395)

Comment: @matthis Bauch i have used your solution.but its not working in my case can you give me some more help

Answer (score 1):

Use CGpoint with direct Cell's property to identify which row is selected and that cell's Uiswitch's state you can identify easily even more accurate and this is the one method am using and it is working fine for me.

```
- (void)switchToggled:(id)sender
{

    CGPoint switchPositionPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:[self tableName]];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableName] indexPathForRowAtPoint:switchPositionPoint];

    BusinessHoursCell *cell = (BusinessHoursCell*)[self.tableName cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    int tag=indexPath.row;

    if (tag==0)
    {
        if (cell.workingDaySwitch.on)
        {
            NSLog(@"its on!");
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"its off!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following scheme:
In cellForRowAtIndexPath:.. set current indexPath to cell. Create protocol with method like `- (void)cellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path changedSwitchStateToState:(BOOL)state` make controller delegate for cells. Cell handles switch state change by calling that delegate method.

In controller you should use something for dataSource(probably custom class) which stores objects which are used to configure the cell and has a method similar to `- (void)changeSwitchStateToState:(BOOL)state atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path` where it gets corresponding object and updates state.