# UISwitch in Table Cell -- determine selected indexPath

Tags: uitableview, uiswitch, accessoryview

I'm using a UISwitch in the accessoryView of a UITableViewCell.

The switch uses target-action to communicate when it has been selected or deselected:

```
switchV.addTarget(self, action: "onChangeSwitch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

The problem is figuring out *which* switch was selected. I know of 3 methods. Each is unsatisfying somewhow.

**1.** I can [use tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142567/how-to-check-status-of-multiple-uiswitch-controls-in-a-table-view-with-custom-ce):

```
switchV.tag = indexPath.row
```

But this sucks if you have sections (and I do), because I need to parse it into and out of a two-number section/row format.

**2.** I could use the data model and store the switch view on the data item that the cell is drawing:

```
dataItem.switch.addTarget(self, action: "onChangeSwitch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
cell.accessoryView = dataItem.switch
```

I can then identify which switch was selected by looping over my data set and doing an identity match with sender. This is a lot of looping, and I don't want to put views in my data model.

**3.** Then there's [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154120/111243) that uses the coordinate of the switch to find the row. Stateless-ish, involves no string parsing or data model muddying, but coordinates, rly? Can I trust it?

```
tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(
  sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
)
```

Is there a better way to get the indexPath of the UISwitch that is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method #3 is pretty good in my opinion. However if you want it to be really clean here's what I would do .

- Declare a custom TableviewCell say CustomTableViewCell and have a delegate protocol called CustomCellDelegate. Here the delegate gets informed like so :

  ```
   -(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch*)switch inCell:(CustomTableViewCell*)cell
  ```
- In cellForRowAtIndexPath set your view controller as the delegate of the cell.
- Add the switch to to your custom cell and make the cell as the target and implement the switch's action method. Inside the action method call the delegate :

  ```
  -(void)switchChanged:(id)sender {
      if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(switchChanged:inCell:])) {
          [self.delegate switchChanged:sender inCell:self];
  }
  ```
- Now in your viewController use the passed in cell in the delegate method to calculate the index path :

  ```
   -(void)switchChanged:(id)sender inCell:(CustomTableViewCell*)cell {
      NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
   }
  ```

Its a bit of work but if you want to do it the proper way , you can .

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an hash which maintains the switch -> data link

```
var switchToData=[UISwitch:yourData]()
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
switchToData[newSwitch]=myData
```

in onChangeSwitch

```
dataChanged=switchToData[switchChanged]
```

The hash will be quite small, the same size of the visible switch....